# Как на Kotlin остановить CountDownTimer (автоматически) , без пользовательского взаимодействия

Tags: kotlin, countdowntimer

```
var t = object : CountDownTimer (10000, 1000)

override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            t.cancle
        }

override fun onFinish() {}
```

Например при каждом `onTick` остановить таймер.
На Java все работает , вот только в Kotlin нет.
Если есть варианты , пожалуйста опишите.

Comment: Покажите рабочий код на Java. В приведенном коде на Котлин методы сами по себе, обьект счетчика сам по себе. Конечно работать вместе это не будет.

Comment: Можно просто пример который будет работать с условием того что "без пользовательского взаимодействия"

Answer (score 1):

```
val timer = object : CountDownTimer(10000 , 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millis: Long) {
        cancel()
    }
    override fun onFinish() {}
}.start()
```